# Is there a quadruple product rule?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The triple product rule in multivariable calculus is widely used.  Can a quadruple product rule equation be written for an equation f(x,y,z,z2)=0?

Comment: What is the triple product rule?

Comment: @Qiaochu: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule

Comment: If you follow the argument given in that wikipedia page, and if I understamnd correctly what you want, you can easily see what the *quadruple product rule* is.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, there is general product rule for $n$-tuple. It is almost the direct consequence of [implicit function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function#Formula_for_two_variables). Assume $n$ variables satisfies $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$, we have
$$\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j}=-{\partial F/\partial x_j\over\partial F/\partial x_i}$$
Then multiply all fractions
$$\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_2}\cdots\frac{\partial x_{n-1}}{\partial x_n}\frac{\partial x_n}{\partial x_1}=(-1)^n{\partial F/\partial x_2\over\partial F/\partial x_1}\cdots{\partial F/\partial x_n\over\partial F/\partial x_{n-1}}{\partial F/\partial x_1\over\partial F/\partial x_n}=(-1)^n$$

Answer (score -2):

This is what would make sense to me: $(fghi)'=f'ghi+fg'hi+fgh'i+fghi'$
You can keep adding $n$ functions to this rule.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what the question is asking about. Look at the link given by anon in his comment.